# Dart: How to pass data from one process to another via streams

Tags: dart, stream, command-line-interface

I need the ability to start two processes from dart, read the input from the first process, manipulate the output in dart and  then send the data to a second process.

Note: in this example I state two processes but in reality I may need to create a pipe line involving any number of processes.

The two process are likely to be long running (assume minutes) and the output must be available as the processes process the data (think tail -f).

To re-inforce the last point the process may output large amounts of data so the data can't be stored in memory hence the stream approach that I've attempted.

I've tried the following but I'm not experienced with streams so I'm not even certain if I'm on the right track.

https://dartpad.dev/3ad46c7e28c80f6735a9ee350091d509

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having come back to this problem, I realize that @alexandre-arduin 's answer is problematic.

The call to:

```dart
  await head.stdout.pipe(stdout);
```

attaches the output of head to the apps own stdout.

This is fine, unless you want to use stdout after the pipe completes.

The issue is that the call to `pipe(stdout)` closes stdout after the pipe completes.

The result is that any later attempt to using the likes of `print('hello')` will fail with a bad state error.

This alternate implementation, calls `addStream` directly (which is what pipe does) but doesn't close stdout after the fact.

```dart
import 'dart:io';

Future<void> main() async {
  final ls = await Process.start('ls', []);
  final head = await Process.start('head', ['-1']);

  // the output from ls is sent to the input of head
  await ls.stdout.pipe(head.stdin).catchError(
    // ignore: avoid_types_on_closure_parameters
    (Object e) {
      // ignore broken pipe after head process exit
    },
    test: (e) => e is SocketException && (e.osError!.message == 'Broken pipe'),
  );

  /// the output of head is sent to the console.
  /// We can't use the normal pipe command is it will close stdout
  /// which will stop our app from outputting any further text to stdout.
  await pipeNoClose(head.stdout, stdout);

  print('done');
}

Future<void> pipeNoClose(Stream<List<int>> stdout, IOSink stdin) async =>
    stdin.addStream(stdout);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Stream.pipe](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.0/dart-async/Stream/pipe.html):

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

void main() async {
  var ls = await Process.start('ls', []);
  var head = await Process.start('head', ['-1']);

  ls.stdout
      .transform(utf8.decoder)
      .transform(const LineSplitter())
      .map((line) => '1: $line\n')
      .transform(utf8.encoder)
      .pipe(head.stdin)
      .catchError(
        (e) {
          // forget broken pipe after head process exit
        },
        test: (e) => e is SocketException && e.osError.message == 'Broken pipe',
      );

  await head.stdout.pipe(stdout);
}
```

Comment: It almost works! If I don't add the \n to the mapping it works great except that the output is all on one line. If I add the \n I'm getting a stack trace:  Write failed (OS Error: Broken pipe, errno = 32), port = 0
#0      _NativeSocket.write (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:789:34)
#1      _RawSocket.write (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1442:15)
#2      _Socket._write (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1862:19)
#3      _SocketStreamConsumer.write (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1617:22)

Comment: My snippet works on linux. What platform are you using?

Comment: Depending on the platform this code is run you perhaps have to use `\n` or `\r\n`.

Comment: I'm running on ubuntu 19.10.

Comment: I'm running it from the cli using: dart pipe_for_stack2.dart

Comment: I'm running dart 2.7 if that makes a difference.

Comment: I can add any other character without a problem. The odd thing is that if I add \r rather than \n I get no output and no exception.

Comment: So I think its a timing issue. If a re-run the script multiple times about 1/3 of the runs complete giving the correct output. I'm thinking the \n cause some break in the buffer chunks which changes the timing. The question is what is closing prematurely.

Comment: So if there are a small no. of files in the working directory it works everytime. this again seems to point to chunking and timing. which seems to suggest that the pattern we are using isn't correct.

Comment: I figured out what's going on. `head.stdin` is closed after `head` has enough entries to output the result. So the output stream of `ls` should be closed once input sink of `head` is closed.

Comment: Since your target process is `head`, it never terminates if you have no newlines. If you do add newlines, it will stop after 10 lines and close its stdin. 
You are then adding more data to a closed stdin because the exit was not recognized by the Dart program. That can explain the "broken pipe" error in the write operation.
I have no idea how to detect that the `head.stdin` has been closed, though.

Comment: I didn't realise that head had a default of 10 lines so that explains half of it. I will read some more on how to detect a stream is closed.

Comment: I need to do a test as I need to know if head completed normally but I'm guessing the process object return when head was started will contain an exit code of 0.