# dart pass data from stdin and stderr to stdin of another process

Tags: asynchronous, dart, process, pipe, command-line-interface

This is really a follow in question from:

[Dart: How to pass data from one process to another via streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59746768/dart-how-to-pass-data-from-one-process-to-another-via-streams)

I using dart to spawn two processes.

Lets call these two processes 'lhs' and 'rhs'.
(lhs - left hand side and rhs - right hand side).

The first process (lhs) writes to stdout and stderr.
I need to pipe all the data from the first process (lhs) to stdin of the second process (rhs).

In the above noted stack overflow the answer was to use the 'pipe' method to stream data from lhs.stdout to rhs.stdin.

Given I now want to write data from both of lhs' streams (stdout and stderr) the pipe method doesn't work as it only supports a single stream and you can't call pipe twice on rhs' stdin (an error is thrown stating correctly that you can't call addStream twice).

So I've tried the following code which seems to partially work but I only see the first character from lhs' stderr stream and then everything completes (the onDone methods are called on both of lhs' stream).

Some detail to help understand what is going on here.

In the below code the 'lhs' is a call to 'dart --version'. When dart writes out its version string it writes it to stderr with nothing being written to stdout.

I use 'head' as the second process - 'rhs'. Its job is to simply received the combined output of stdout and stderr from lhs and print it to the console.

The output from a run of the below code is:

```
lhs exitCode=0
done
listen: stderr
listen: stderr written
done err
```

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:cli';
import 'dart:io';

Future<void> main() async {

  var dart = start('dart', ['--version']);
  var head = start('head', ['-n', '5']);

  pipeTo(dart, head);

}

void pipeTo(Future<Process> lhs, Future<Process> rhs) {
  var complete = Completer<void>();

  // wait for the lhs and rhs processes to
  // start and then start piping lhs
  // output to the rhs input.
  lhs.then((lhsProcess) {
    rhs.then((rhsProcess) {
      // write stdout from lhs to stdin of rhs
      lhsProcess.stdout.listen((datum) {
        print('listen');
        rhsProcess.stdin.add(datum);
        print('listen written');
      }
      , onDone: () {
        print('done');
        complete.complete();
      }
      , onError: (Object e, StackTrace s) =>
              print('onError $e')
      ,cancelOnError: true);

      // write stderr from lhs to stdin of rhs.
      lhsProcess.stderr.listen((datum) {
        print('listen: stderr');
        rhsProcess.stdin.add(datum);
        print('listen: stderr written');
      }
      , onDone: () {
        print('done err');
        if (!complete.isCompleted) complete.complete();
      }
      , onError: (Object e, StackTrace s) =>
              print('onError $e')
      , cancelOnError: true);

      lhsProcess.exitCode.then((exitCode) {
        print('lhs exitCode=$exitCode');
      });

      rhsProcess.exitCode.then((exitCode) {
        print('rhs exitCode=$exitCode');
      });
    });
  });

  waitFor(complete.future);
}

Future<Process> start(String command, List<String> args) async {
  var process = Process.start(
    command,
    args,
  );
  return process;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution of using `listen()` to forward events to `rhsProcess.stdin` will work. You could clean it up by using await in place of the `then()` callbacks and remove the `Completer`. You could make `pipeTo()` return a `Future<void>` and alternatively use `waitFor(pipeTo())` if desired.

Here's a condensed example:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

void main() {
  var dart = Process.start('dart', ['--version']);
  var head = Process.start('head', ['-n', '1']);
  pipeTo(dart, head);
}

Future<void> pipeTo(Future<Process> lhs, Future<Process> rhs) async {
  var lhsProcess = await lhs;
  var rhsProcess = await rhs;
  lhsProcess.stdout.listen(rhsProcess.stdin.add);
  lhsProcess.stderr.listen(rhsProcess.stdin.add);
  rhsProcess.stdout.transform(utf8.decoder).listen(print);
}
```

Note: I pass `-n 1` to head otherwise the program never exits.

Comment: I tried that but I get zero output from the app. I tried substituting cat for dart and cat'ing a local file just incase it was a problem with using stderr but I got the same result - zero output.

Comment: So I just ran another test using dart --version and then cat and I now get the expected output. When I run the head version I'm getting the broken pipe problem again that I had with the original post (and forgot about). So I still need to work out how to handle one of the processes shutting down in a graceful manner. The other problem is that the code doesn't shutdown at the end of the output.

Comment: I's also recommend to add `stdin.close()` because some programs require to explicitly set EOF for standard input.

Answer (score 0):

```dart
Future<void> main() async {
  var dart = start('cat', ['/var/log/syslog']);
  var head = start('head', ['-n', '5']);

  await pipeTo2(dart, head);

}

Future<void> pipeTo2(Future<Process> lhs, Future<Process> rhs) async {
  // wait for both processes to start
  var lhsProcess = await lhs;
  var rhsProcess = await rhs;

  // send the lhs stdout to the rhs stdin
  lhsProcess.stdout.listen(rhsProcess.stdin.add);

  // send the lhs stderr to the rhs stdin
  lhsProcess.stderr.listen(rhsProcess.stdin.add).onDone(() {
    rhsProcess.stdin.close();
  });

  // send the rhs stdout and stderr to the console
  rhsProcess.stdout.listen(stdout.add);
  rhsProcess.stderr.listen(stderr.add);

  // wait for rhs to finish.
  // if it finishes before the lhs does we will get
  // a broken pipe error which is fine so we can 
  // suppress it.
  await rhsProcess.stdin.done.catchError(
    (Object e) {
      // forget broken pipe after rhs terminates before lhs
    },
    test: (e) => e is SocketException && e.osError.message == 'Broken pipe',
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case you have to wait the first process to end (but you should be able to implement this easily) I use something like this:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

Future<void> main() async {
  var result = await Process.run('dart', ['--version']);
  if (result.exitCode != 0) {
    throw StateError(result.stderr);
  }

  var process = await Process.start('head', ['-n', '1']);
  var buffer = StringBuffer();
  var errBuffer = StringBuffer();
  // ignore: unawaited_futures
  process.stdout
      .transform(utf8.decoder)
      .forEach((_value) => buffer.write(_value));
  // ignore: unawaited_futures
  process.stderr
      .transform(utf8.decoder)
      .forEach((_value) => errBuffer.write(_value));

  process.stdin.writeln('${result.stdout}${result.stderr}');

  var exitCode = await process.exitCode;
  if (exitCode != 0) {
    throw StateError('$exitCode - $errBuffer');
  }
  print('$buffer');
}
```